# Modified and created a new python class for generating a report of metrics for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I initially posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55468376/5675288) on SO. I have come up with an answer for the same. Basically, given two dicts of models and parameters, user can create an object, and get the report in 5 steps.

Following is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, recall_score, precision_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = cancer.target
target = df['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns='target', axis=1), target, test_size=0.4, random_state=13, stratify=target)

class ClfSwitcher(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, model=RandomForestClassifier()):
        """
        A Custom BaseEstimator that can switch between classifiers.
        :param estimator: sklearn object - The classifier
        """ 

        self.model = model


    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.model.fit(X, y)
        return self


    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        return self.model.predict(X)


    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self.model.predict_proba(X)

    def score(self, X, y):
        return self.estimator.score(X, y)

class report(ClfSwitcher):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.grid = None
        self.full_report = None
        self.concise_report = None
        self.scoring_metrics = {
            'precision': precision_score,
            'recall': recall_score,
            'f1': f1_score,
            'roc_auc': roc_auc_score
        }


    def griddy(self, pipeLine, parameters, **kwargs):
        self.grid = GridSearchCV(pipeLine, parameters, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)


    def fit_grid(self, X_train, y_train=None, **kwargs):
        self.grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    def make_grid_report(self):
        self.full_report = pd.DataFrame(self.grid.cv_results_)

    @staticmethod
    def get_names(col):
        return col.__class__.__name__

    @staticmethod
    def calc_score(col, metric):
        return round(metric(y_test, col.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)), 4)


    def make_concise_report(self):
        self.concise_report = pd.DataFrame(self.grid.cv_results_)
        self.concise_report['model_names'] = self.concise_report['param_cst__model'].apply(self.get_names)
        self.concise_report = self.concise_report.sort_values(['model_names', 'rank_test_score'], ascending=[True, False]) \
                                                .groupby(['model_names']).head(1)[['param_cst__model', 'model_names']] \
                                                .reset_index(drop=True)

        for metric_name, metric_func in self.scoring_metrics.items():
            self.concise_report[metric_name] = self.concise_report['param_cst__model'].apply(self.calc_score, metric=metric_func)

        self.concise_report = self.concise_report[['model_names', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1', 'roc_auc', 'param_cst__model']]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ClfSwitcher()),
])

parameters = [
    {
        'cst__model': [RandomForestClassifier()],
        'cst__model__n_estimators': [10, 20],
        'cst__model__max_depth': [5, 10],
        'cst__model__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [SVC()],
        'cst__model__C': [10, 20],
        'cst__model__kernel': ['linear'],
        'cst__model__gamma': [0.0001, 0.001]
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [LogisticRegression()],
        'cst__model__C': [13, 17],
        'cst__model__penalty': ['l1', 'l2']
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [GradientBoostingClassifier()],
        'cst__model__n_estimators': [10, 50],
        'cst__model__max_depth': [3, 5],
        'cst__model__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2]
    }
]

my_report = report()
my_report.griddy(pipeline, parameters, scoring='f1')
my_report.fit_grid(X_train, y_train)
my_report.make_concise_report()
my_report.concise_report
```

Comment: After pip install sklearn (as I didn't have it), when I run your code I get `TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`. Does your code run with a specific version of sklearn?

Comment: Can you please post traceback? I'm guessing this has to do with `pandas` ? `drop()` is a part of that only.

Comment: This is what I have: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "20190404a.py", line 19, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns='target', axis=1), target, test_size=0.4, random_state=13, stratify=target)
TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`

Comment: `pd.__version__ 0.24.1
np.__version__ 1.15.4
sklearn.__version__ 0.20.2` These are the versions installed in my system.